# FAQ and Midifiles

Tags: discussion

There seems to be an avalanche of questions that boil down to "I've downloaded an SMF off Geocities and I'm playing it back in Windows Media Player and it sounds crappy".

I think there are several misconceptions at work here, and the answers boils down to "yo, that SMF you downloaded off Geocities and the WMP soft synth - neither are meant to sound good, neither is meant for your consumption. Just leave it, ok?".

Would we perhaps want to put that on the FAQ somehow?

Answer (score 4):

We don't really have a Frequently-Asked-On-Topic-Questions section, the FAQ is for questions about the Stack Exchange platform (with sections for stuff about our specific site, like scope).

Any duplicate questions should be closed as such, pointing to the best version of the question.